# Is there a way to modify ioncube files to make it more secure

Tags: ioncube

Basically I want to set a script that unless user insert "?hithisisme" the ioncube won't run. However, I run afoul of their anti corruption file mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I think that anti corruption file mechanism uses also date of creation / date of modification so if you even add something to file and remove and date of file modification will change, there will be corrupted info (tested myself just right now) .

To achieve what you want you have to create .htaccess file with:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file prepend.php
```

and in prepend.php you have to put:

```
<?php
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?hithisisme') === false) {       
   exit;  
}
```

On my localhost it works without any problems